# Initiate google_auth_oauthlib flow() without json key

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm currently developing an OAuth2 Google Authentication. In the Google Documentation (https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/oauth.html), they use the following to initiate the flow:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

However, for security reasons, I would like to avoid using a json key file. I haven't found any useful resources on the internet so far to do so. Is there another method to initiate the flow (perhaps with an ENVVAR or something else)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .env file in the root directory of your project. This file will store your client credentials and other sensitive information. Add the following lines to the .env file

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=your_client_id
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=your_client_secret
```

Install the python-dotenv library by running `pip install python-dotenv`

Then in your code, import the dotenv module and load the environment variables from the .env file before initializing the OAuth2 flow:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Create the OAuth2 flow object using environment variables
flow = Flow.from_client_config(
    client_config={
        "web": {
            "client_id": os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
            "client_secret": os.environ["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback"],
            "scopes": ["openid", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"],
        }
    },
    redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback",
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works to open the OAuth2 Google page, but for the call, I tried the same method to iniate the flow (I just add the parameter `state=session["state"]`) but I got the error: "oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) Unauthorized"

Comment: @Dasil 
Verify that your OAuth2 client is properly set up in the Google Cloud Console. Ensure that the client ID and client secret you are using are authorized to access the requested scopes and redirect URI.

Check that the redirect URI specified in the client configuration matches the one set up in your Google Cloud Console. In your case, the redirect URI is "http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback". Ensure that this exact URI is added to the list of authorized redirect URIs for your OAuth2 client.

Comment: Thank for your answer.
The OAuth2 client is properly set up as it worked perfectly with the json key and I use the exact same code as above (with my real redirect uri), which works for opening the flow for the connexion pop-up but not for the flow in the callback function